# Static DateTime for testing

Tags: .net, vb.net, testing, fitnesse

We have a DateTime Service that pulls the Database date down when we need to use a Date. Now, If I want to run a test using "Todays" Date using FitNesse, What would be the easiest way of creating a way to have (OurService).CurrentDate be static?

We have a control that ads Days,Years, or Months to the current date.. and I would like to be able to test this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, add a method to pull the date from "somewhere" ("somewhere" is an implementation detail). For example, in my code:

```
public class X {
    Date now = new Date ();
}
```

is replaced with:

```
public class X {
    Date now = now ();
    protected Date now () { return new Date (); }
}
```

I can now extend X in my tests to override `now()` with something that returns a fixed date.

Also add a test which calls the original implementation but which ignores the result (well, you can check that the result is within a range of "now"). This test just makes sure that the old date pulling code continues to work.

Comment: So if I was testing a control that called this class from inside of it (thus not being able to pass in the DateTime value), how would I get the new value into it? If I create a new class and inherit, the control would still be calling X?

Comment: You would rewrite your control to allow you to pass in an instance of X. From the TDD lore: Static methods and internal calls to `new` can't be tested. You must wrap them with a factory method.